# Interpreting eigenvalues of non-normalized covariance matrix of time-series measurements

Tags: linear-systems, system-identification

[Cross-posted from physics stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/796620/interpreting-non-normalized-covariance-matrix-eigenvalues-as-physical-actions)

**Summary:** Eigenvalues of a "non-normalized" covariance matrix of time-series measurements from a linear system have units of Action (energy * time).  Can we interpret this to obtain meaningful statistical thresholds?

Recently I've been doing some volunteer work on an open-source system identification tool for mechanisms driven by permanent-magnet DC motors.  These are fairly close to an ideal LTI system, and accordingly we've had success approaching the problem with OLS and derived techniques.

Our analysis involves time-series measurements of a mechanical system's voltage, velocity, and acceleration as a driving signal is applied.  We perform an OLS fit of the motor's voltage balance equation, with the noisiest measured variable (typically acceleration) as the dependent variable, and the others as predictors.  The parameters from this OLS are then used to compute control gains for the motor.

This methodology works quite well in most cases, but it can be hard for inexperienced users to diagnose when the fit is invalid due to undersampling and a calculated control gain cannot be trusted.  One promising approach seems to be to perform a principal component analysis to determine which signals are well-sampled enough to warrant inclusion in the OLS (such as when the driving signal undersamples some portion of the dynamics).  For example, we can look for eigenvalues of the non-normalized covariance matrix (the data matrix multiplied by its transpose) that are below a significance threshold, and remove from the fit the parameter that is "closest" to the matching eigenvector.

But, while we've found this to work well in practice, I'm stumped as to how to interpret the (experimentally-determined) threshold for the above procedure.  A naive dimensional analysis suggests that, after appropriate physical conversions, the "threshold" has units of `joule * second` - physical units of Action.  What does this mean?  Can we estimate an appropriate threshold from first principles?

More generally, is there a conceptual reason that Action seems to be the natural unit of "sample size" in a statistical physics experiment like this?  I know system identification is not "traditionally" viewed as statistical physics, but there seem to be parallels here and I wonder if interpretation can be helped by the analogy.

Comment: To answer the question specifically, more info is probably needed. This sounds like principle component analysis, though. The idea is that you get information about the spread/variance (eigenvalue) and direction (corresponding eigenvector) of the data. Looking up the Karhunen-Loeve Theorem may give some valuable insights.

Comment: @Baddioes This is explicitly PCA, yes.  I'm struggling to interpret the magnitudes of the principal components, to place it entirely in the language of that methodology.  Most PCA guides i've seen choose the dimensionality reduction heuristically ("it looks like only these components are significant") rather than rigorously interpreting the variances.

Comment: I may be telling you things you already know, but perfect dimensionality reduction requires prior knowledge of the signal. I don't know how "well sampled enough" or undersampling does in your scenario (not a motor guy), so I don't really know for sure what would happen to its principle components. The eigenvectors of the covariance matrix give an orthonormal basis for the signal. Expanding the signal into this basis, truncating the basis, and then representing the signal in the truncated basis gives an optimal approximation of the signal in the L2-norm sense.

Comment: The MSE of your approximation is the sum of the eigenvalues corresponding to the discarded eigenvectors. But again, knowing which eigenvalues correspond to undesirable components and which correspond to components you wish to keep is case dependent. The only thing that you can really know is that any white noise is distributed equally along all principle directions, whereas your signal will hopefully be distributed across a select few directions.

Comment: @Baddioes Unfortunately, the noise is very much not white noise.  The principal sources of noise are mechanical vibrations and numerical errors from finite differencing.  The sort of case we're looking to detect is rather simple (it is true you need knowledge of the signal to do anything substantial) - we'd like to let the user know when they've run a test routine that lacked sufficiently-rich dynamics to identify the system (for example, if you run only a quasistatic voltage sweep at a constant rate, you can only fit steady-state behavior - the test did not sample the dynamics).

Comment: I imagine *some* knowledge of the system is going to have to be introduced in some way, but I'm lost for how to leverage what we know, exactly.  I think the threshold we've found may work in practice largely due to tight coupling to our "sweep + step" identification routine (the failure we can reliably catch with it is data from a test that involved a sweep but not a step)

Comment: We'd like to eventually support arbitrary (user-specified) test routines (stairstep signals seem promising), but we're apprehensive about doing this without giving our users feedback on whether the routine they ran can capture the dynamics of their system.